# Is it possible to do a Lazy Load of data from ContentProviders?

Tags: android, listview

I want to use a `ListView` to display Contacts with phone numbers. Its taking too long to load the contacts as there are a couple thousand contacts. Is there a way to do a lazy load of data from `ContentProvider`s? In my case the Contact information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do a Lazy Load of data from ContentProviders?

Yes, use a [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). Specifically the [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to get data from a `ContentProvider`.

The `Loader` API was introduced in Android 3.0, but it is also available for earlier versions of Android using the [Support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).